# Certificate and digital signing

Tags: encryption, digital

I need a little guidance on how to implement signing of documents in a web based document distribution system we are developing.
  At its simplest, user A will be logging into the website and create a Data Package. Word/Pdfs can be added to the package. User A will sign this document(s) using a digital certificate. User A might assign this to other users for reviewing the documents. They may sign the documents as well.

Now I know how to digitally sign data with C#. What I don't know is how to generate a certificate when each user logs into the website. The site is secured with  DigiCert certificate.

What approach should I take to generate a digital certificate for each user? Once I have a .pfx file I believe I can store it in the database and use that.. Any guidance on this matter will be greatly appreciated!

thanks

Comment: It seems odd to me that the application is designed for secure document signing - and yet you hold all the keys involved in the system.  Shouldn't the *user* hold their own key?  You shouldn't be storing PFX files for people.

Comment: You'd setup a Certificate Authority with a Registration Authority. This is not a programming question.

Comment: @LukeJoshuaPark Thanks for your input.So the document should be signed locally then uploaded to the site?

Comment: @MaartenBodewes   DigiCert is the CA right?

Comment: @Gulumal DigiCert is **a** CA for sure. But certificates used for HTTPS/TLS are meant for *entity authentication* rather than *non-repudiation*, so you have to get your certificate from a CA that provides that kind of certificates, or setup your own.

Comment: Heh, I wrote entitity rather than entity in the comment :)

Answer (score 0):

> I take to generate a digital certificate for each user? Once I have a .pfx file I believe I can store it in the database and use that..

This is what I call "naive approach" (read simplistic). You consider to store (maybe even generate) keypairs for the users in a web application. The biggest isssue with this approach is that someone with low-level access to the system (admins) or if database is leakt could gain access to the user's private key. To have a secure solution (considering signing), the private key may not leave its user

Doing everything in a web environment, you may consider using [SubtleCrypto](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SubtleCrypto) or other client site libraries, however at this point of time I see no reasonable way to manage the keys for pure web apps. Maybe you can store the user's keys and certificate in a [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API/Using_the_Web_Storage_API), but it leaves some space for mallignant scripts to leak the keys.

Many real life secure solutions are working with secure modules (e. g. crypo cards), unfortunatelly the web libraries have no access to the modules (usually exposed as pkcs11 interface). As a solution usually the signing piece runs as custom code  on user's computer. Before it was ActiveX, Applet,.. now it is often a "driver" exposed as a web server bound to "localhost" so the signig service can be used as web api from web applications.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable input!